# Running a foreach loop in a php function while creating an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Hi i'm trying to create a new array in a php function from a foreach loop but what i'm doing isn't working... any advise please :)

```
$data = array(
  'action' => 'add',
  'send_confirmation' => true,
  'signups' => array(
  foreach ($signups as $signup) {
    array(
      'first_name' => $signup['first_name'],
      'last_name' => $signup['last_name'],
      'email' => $signup['email'],
      'mobile' => $signup['mobile'],
      'ticket_id' => $signup['ticket_id']
    ),
  }
  )
);
```

Comment: What does `$signups` look like?  You may not even need a loop.

Comment: WOW! The dupe is eerily similar!